# Domino Effect going off

Tags: modeling

For some reason when I try to create dominoes, this happens. I have simply made an array following the curve, applied rigid body active to it, then used P in edit mode to seperate the artifacts. However, when I play animation, it just all stacks to center. ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROGfEtoBxlQ)

Edit: I noticed that the origin axis of all the split objects (596 objects). are all at the center of the original object on which I used the array

Comment: wow, this looks awesome :D Have you used constraints or used "connected" from menu?

Comment: @Blunder Right? I love how it looks but it was so not intended. I did not use any constraints, but I'm not sure what the "connected" is. I haven't used it I believe, I'm a bit new to blender :D

Comment: As you mention in your edit, the origin is not set correctly for each of the separated objects. You need to move the origin to centre of mass for each of them.

Comment: @RichSedman do I have to manually do it for everyone? ._.

Comment: Select all the dominoes and do "Object -> Set Origin -> Origin to Geometry" and it should fix everything?

Comment: As @ronjensen says, you can select them all and set Origin to Geometry (or even better is Origin to Center of Mass) to do them all in one action. Also, while selected do Ctrl+A and Apply Scale to make sure the correct scale and dimensions are used in the simulation.

Comment: Ooh yeah it worked neattt! tyty

Comment: Great. Please add an answer to your own question and mark it as 'Accepted' (you'll gain some reputation for this and others can more easily find your solution).